# Use dictwriter and write unstructured data into csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

[Output CSv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hb2z5.jpg)I am currently trying to put the data from a file into csv file using python.
My data looks as follows:

```
data_list{} = [{'row': '0', 't0': '8.69E-005', 'elems': ' 4 96 187 ', 'Tspan': '5E-006', 'NP': '625','wave0': '123.65 333.56 3333.78 567.89 345678.77 34E-08'}]
```

My output should look like this :

```
 row  t0        elems Tspan  NP  wave0
 0    8.69E-005  4    5E-006 625  123.65
                 96               333.56
                 187              3333.78
                                  567.89
                                  345678.77
                                  34E-08
```

First comes header and then values underneath them. I was succesfull in getting the header part and the row parts for all except for elems and wave0.

python code:

```
 with open('cc.csv','w', newline='') as out_file:
     writer = csv.DictWriter(out_file, fieldnames=data_list[0].keys())
     writer.writeheader()
     for data in data_list:
          writer.writerow(data)
```

Comment: You output is definitely not in CSV format! Why do you want to use the csv module for that?

Comment: i am putting the data into cc.csv file . And i was able to write the data for few columns, but for elems adn wave0 , i want the data to come in next rows based on the delimiter space.

Comment: What would the output look like if there were two elements in data_list?

Comment: Output would look like this                                                                       First row : row  t0, Second row: 0    8.69E-005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are after the dictionary inside your `data_list` variable. In order to get your desired output, you are going to need to do a little bit of work:

Your list of one dictionary:

```
data_list = [{'row': '0', 't0': '8.69E-005', 'elems': ' 4 96 187 ', 'Tspan': '5E-006', 'NP': '625','wave0': '123.65 333.56 3333.78 567.89 345678.77 34E-08'}]
```

First, you need to define your output columns:

```
output_cols = ['row', 't0', 'elems', 'Tspan', 'NP', 'wave0']
```

Then you need to create lists from the `values` of the dictionary and subsequently `*zip*` all those lists together:

```
# Python2
from itertools import izip_longest
import csv

data = [data_list[0].get(x).strip().split(" ") for x in output_cols]
data = izip_longest(*data)
with open('somefile.csv','w') as outfile:
    file_writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter="\t", lineterminator="\n")
    file_writer.writerow(output_cols)
    file_writer.writerows(data)
```

If you are using python3, then `from itertools import izip_longest` should be replaced with `from itertools import zip_longest`.

Please note the answer assumes that all your data is that first dictionary (`data_list[0]`). If your actual list is longer than that, please share more data.

Content of `somefile.csv`:

```
row     t0      elems   Tspan   NP      wave0
0     8.69E-005   4     5E-006  625     123.65
                 96                     333.56
                 187                    3333.78
                                        567.89
                                        345678.77
                                        34E-08
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: somefile.csv is not valid CSV (RFC 4180)

Comment: I am not sure I follow. Could you please elaborate?